# What is the correct way to Castle ActiveRecord SessionScope in desktop applications?

Tags: nhibernate, desktop-application, windows-authentication, castle-activerecord, session-scope

In a Desktop Application using Castle ActiveRecord

I open a SessionScope and keep alive for the application lifetime, I dispose this at the end of the application.

When I need to do "something" I do it, and if I need transactional operations, I create TransactionsScope(s) an nested transactions as needed, after a transaction is ended correctly i flushes the session and continue to keep alive the SessionScope.

Is this aproach correct? or I need to open a SessionScope at the start of a bl process and closes it at the end? if yes, why?.

I uses LazyLoad and a process can call another process as needed, at the same time a single process can runs alone.

-update-
the correct aproach is to open a sessionscope at form level, but as the ar sessionscope is created at a stack way, i can't have more than 1 sessionscope at the same level, i only have a sessionscope into another one, someone knows howto resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved:
implementing IThreadScopeInfo managing a stack collection.
i'm starting to think castle ar is deprecated.

thank you.